# Show that the sequence $(A_n)_{n≥1}$ in $L(l_1)$ does not converge to zero

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

For any $n ≥ 1$, define a linear operator $A_n : l_1 → l_1$ by
$$A_nx = (0, . . . , 0, x_{n+1}, x_{n+2}, . . .), ∀x = (x_1, x_2, . . .) ∈ l_1.$$
Show that

1. For any $x ∈ l_1$, we have $\lim_{n→∞} A_nx = 0$.
2. The sequence $(A_n)_{n≥1}$ in $L(l_1)$ does not converge to zero

The first part is fairly understandable. I'll probably go about it saying that as $n→∞$, for each non-zero $x_i$ there is an infinite number of zeros preceding it, so $A_nx→ (0,0,...)=0$.

But, I'm unsure of the distinction between the expressions in part 1 and 2. Surely if $lim_{n→∞} A_nx = 0$ then $(A_n)_{n≥1}$ converges to $0$?

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, the limit is in $\ell^1$. You need to check that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|A_nx\|_1=0$. Since
$$
\|A_nx\|_1=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty|x_k|,
$$
it follows from the fact that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty|x_k|<\infty$.

For the second part, the convergence is in the operator norm. It is clear that $\|A_nx\|_1\le\|x\|_1$ and $\|A_n\|\le1$. I leave it to you to check that in fact $\|A_n\|=1$.

Comment: Lost on proving $||A_n|| = 1$. I know i need to try and show $||A_n||≤1$ but I just cant figure out how to do that.

Comment: Take $x$ such that $x_{k}=0$ if $1\le k\le n$. Then $A_nx=x$.

Comment: Figured it out through the Lemma, $$||A|| = sup_{x\neq0} \frac{||Ax||}{||x||} = sup_{||x||=1} ||Ax||$$